# How to check the value of a field in TWIG?

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

Have created a field of type "List (text)" and I want to display a text according to the value of the field. How to do this ? Thank you

```
{% if store.field_professionnel_ets_statut %}
  micro-entreprenneur
{% else if store.field_professionnel_ets_statut %}
  entreprenneur
{% endif %}
```

https://ibb.co/MGS05ZB

The "field_professionnel_ets_statut" field can have the values :

- micro-entreprise
- entreprise

Here's what I want :

- If the field with the value "micro-entreprise" display "micro-entreprenneur".
- If the field with the value "entreprise" display "entreprenneur".

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if "micro-entreprise" in store.field_professionnel_ets_statut %}
  micro-entreprenneur
{% else if "entreprise" in store.field_professionnel_ets_statut %}
  entreprenneur
{% endif %}
```

this may help!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I have a blank page with this message "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Answer (score 1):

Try this :) :

```
{% if store.field_professionnel_ets_statut === 'micro-entreprise' %}
   micro-entreprenneur
{% elseif store.field_professionnel_ets_statut === 'entreprise' %}
   entreprenneur
{% endif %}
```

Comment: There is an error in the code. For it to work you have to put `elseif`

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake :)